# Illuminati with prediction machine that only works when the prediction won't be used

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember a story where the Illuminati made a machine that could predict the future. However, there was a snag: the machine only worked when the user did not intend to use the information. Therefore, their project failed.

I think I heard the story 2-5 years ago. It might be that I read it on a conspiracy theory website or heard it in a podcast by a conspiracy theorist.
Does anyone know of a source for this story?